# C++: Operator [] overloading for vector<>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, overloading, stdvector

I'm currently trying to overload the operator `[]` on vectors. I'm trying to get this operator to work as in Matlab or Python for negative indexes or indexes greater than the vector's length. My problem isn't to get the right result, but to actually overload the operator, knowing I will use the non-overloaded operator in the overloading code. I need it for vectors of a specific class but it would be even better if it worked for any `vector`.

Right now my code is:
header:

```
MyClass std::vector::operator[](std::vector<MyClass> const vector,int const idx) const;
```

source:

```
Myclass vector::operator[](vector<MyClass> const vector,int const idx) const {
    n=vector.size()
    if((idx>=0) && (idx<n)){
        return vector[idx];
    }
    else if(idx<0){
        return vector[n+idx%n]
    }
    else{
        return vector[idx%n]
    }
}
```

And I get the errors:

```
error: 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector' used without template parameters
error: non-member function 'MyClass operator[](std::vector<MyClass>, int)' cannot have cv-qualifier
error: 'MyClass operator[](std::vector<MyClass>, int)' must be a nonstatic member function
```

I'm sorry if this problem has already been discussed, but I couldn't find it...
Thank you very much in advance for your answers !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Aganju: that doesn't answer the question and is wrong.

Comment: @Aganju: `vector::operator[]` performs no bound checking. `vector::at` is instead forced to perform bound checking.

Comment: I stand corrected. I could have sworn it's the other way round.

Comment: Although it's a shame there isn't another built-in method (or even the operator itself, since I think it's useless outside of bounds) doing what I'm looking for, it would come in pretty handy in many cases !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is about the syntax:

```
vector::operator[]
```

should be

```
vector<MyClass>::operator[]
```

---

However, you cannot arbitrarily redefine operators of classes that you do not own. What you can do is create your own `MyVector` class that publicly inherits from `vector`:

```
struct MyVector : std::vector<MyClass>
{
    MyClass& operator[](std::size_t index)
    { 
        // ...
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But then I will have to change all my code because I already use vectors everywhere... I guess I'll just deal locally with the issue of indexes going out of the bounds, even if it's not as elegant^^

Comment: question, is it not guaranteed that `operator[]` doesn't modify any `MyClass` member?

Comment: @codekaizer Well I believe it shouldn't, since it's not overloading the operator [] for MyClass anyway!

Comment: sorry I meant `MyVector`. I'm expecting for it to also have a `const`-equivalent `operator[]` which will return a `const_reference`. Shouldn't you overload both?

Comment: @codekaizer: yes, a real implementation would have that as well.